# is there a reject policy in kafka like prefetch limit in RabbitMQ?

Tags: apache-kafka, policy

when slow consumer situation and the message size exceed the log.retention.bytes or log.segment.bytes . kafka default delete the message. does kafka has the policy like prefetch limit in rabbitMQ . when the kafka is full and the producer will be blocked